# Selecting the latest values given data with missing records

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

... where "missing records" are identical to the last recorded value, hence no record.

This *may* be subjective, but I'm hoping there's a standardised way of doing this.

So, let's say I have a bunch of analytics in a MySQL table. There is some missing information, but as mentioned above, that's because their previous value is the same as the current value.

```
table "table":

id    value      datetime
1     5          1285891200    // Today
1     4          1285804800    // Yesterday
2     18         1285804800    // Yesterday
2     16         1285771094    // The day before yesterday
```

As you can see, I don't have a value for today for id 2.

If I wanted to pull the "most recent value" from this table (that is, 1's "today", and 2's "yesterday", how do I do that? I've achieved it by running the following query:

`SELECT id, value FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY datetime DESC) as bleh GROUP BY id`

Which utilizes a subquery to order the data first, and then I rely on "GROUP BY" to pick the first value (which, since it is ordered, is the most recent) from each id. However, I don't know if shoving a subquery in there is the best way to get the most recent value.

How would you do it?

The desired table:

```
id    value      datetime
1     5          1285891200    // Today
2     18         1285804800    // Yesterday
```

Thanks...

Comment: What value do you want for Yesterday ? 4 or 18 , or both ?

Comment: good point - I've updated the question to include the desired table. In this case, I want the most recent value for each id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotta love MySQL for allowing an order by in a subquery.  That's not allowed by the SQL standard :)

You could rewrite the query in a standards complaint way like:

```
select  *
from    YourTable a
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable b
        where   a.id = b.id
        and     a.datetime < b.datetime
        )
```

In case there are duplicates that you can't split apart in the subquery, you can `group by` and then pick an arbitrary value:

```
select  a.id
,       max(a.value)
,       max(a.datetime)
from    YourTable a
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable b
        where   a.id = b.id
        and     a.datetime < b.datetime
        )
group by
        a.id
```

This chooses the maximum `a.value` sharing the latest `datetime`.  Now `datetime` is the same for all duplicate rows, but standard SQL doesn't know that, so you have to specify a way to pick from the equal days.  Here, I'm using `max`, but `min` or even `avg` would work just as well.

Comment: Nice! Okay - but we're assuming that there is more than one value per id, so we can compare and get the "latest" - but this doesn't account for the corner case where there is only one value, because it won't satisfy `a.datetime < b.datetime`. ;) I worked around that with a separate query to make sure there are always 2, but just food for thought. :)

Comment: @Julian H. Lam: The condition is behind `not exists`, so if it's not satisfied, it will be included in the result set.  I'd expect the query to work if there's only one value.